# Memory overlap / disabled notice in dmesg. Is this related to wifi and Bluetooth autoconnection issues?

Tags: boot, wireless, 22.04, bluetooth

Can I ignore this?  What does it mean?  Is it related to Bluetooth and wifi connection issues?

I am seeing the following memory overlap message.

```
sudo dmesg --level=err,warn
...
pnp 00:04: disabling [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] because it overlaps 0000:00:02.0 BAR 9 [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
...
```

When I Google this, there are a lot of matches in logs for this exact string, in quotes, but after going through them for an an hour nobody seems to be talking about this specific message. I started looking at logs because of two problems. Wifi won't autoconnect, even though it's set to (a hidden network), and also I have to manually click on 'connect' in the Bluetooth settings every time I turn my headphones on.

Thanks for any help.